# MongoDB: Making sure referenced document still exists

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have two types of MongoDB documents: 'Projects' and 'Tasks'. A Project can have many tasks. In my case it is more suitable to link the documents rather than embed.

When a user wants to save a task I first verify that the project the task is being assigned to exists, like so:

```
// Create new task
var task = new Task(data);
// Make sure project exists
Project.findById(task.project, function(err, project) {
  if(project) {
    // If project exists, save task
    task.save(function(err){
      ...    
    });
  } else {
    // Project not found
  }
});
```

My concern is that if another user happens to delete the project after the `Project.findById()` query is run, but before the task is saved, the task will be created anyway without a referenced project.

Is this a valid concern? Is there any practice that would prevent this from happening, or is this just something that has to be faced with MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically yes, this is something you need to face when using MongoDB. But it's not really a big deal as it's rarely someone to delete a project and another person is unaware of it and creating task for that project. I would not use the `if` statement to check the project status, rather just leave task created as a bad record. You can either manually remove those bad records or schedule a cron task to clean them.

Comment: Makes sense. I like the idea of a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

The way you appear to be doing it, i.e, with two separate Models -- not subdocuments (hard to tell without seeing the Models), I guess you will have that race condition. The `if` won't help. You'd need to take advantage of the atomic modifiers to avoid this issue, and using separate Models (each being it's own MongoDB collection), the [atomic modifiers are not available](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations). In SQL world, you'd use a transaction to ensure consistentcy. Similarly, with a document store like MongoDB, you'd make each Task a subdocument of a Project, and then just `.push()` new tasks. But perhaps your use case necessitates separate, unrelated Models. MongoDB is great for offering that flexibility, but it enables you to retain SQL-thinking without being SQL, which can lead to design problems.

More to the point, though, the race condition you're worried about doesn't seem to be a big deal. After all, the Project could be deleted after the task is saved, too. You obviously have a method for cleaning that up. One more cleanup function isn't the end of the world -- probably a good thing to have in your back pocket anyway.